# sudo su command is not working

Tags: sudo, users

My sudo user is not working. i am using ubuntu 18.04 
Error while sudo su on terminal:-
sudo: /usr/local/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Comment: `sudo` for my \*ubuntu system is located in /usr/bin/sudo ; /usr/local/bin is for user created scripts so why would it be in there?  Are you using Ubuntu? or something that isn't Ubuntu?  *If you are really running a Ubuntu system, then this is probably a huge clue on your fix anyway*

Comment: hey @guiverc i am using ubuntu 18.04